# How to decompose root iswap into root cz and single-qubit gates

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Id like to decompose root iswap gate into root cz (not cz or cx) and single-qubit gates.

1)Is it possible to decompose like that?

2)Is there a way to do such a decomposition with qiskit, qutip, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

So, you are given the $\sqrt{iSWAP}$ gate

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import iSwapGate

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(iSwapGate().power(1/2), [0, 1])
qc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

defined by the unitary operator
$$
\sqrt{iSWAP} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i & 0 \\
0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and you want to decompose it by using $\sqrt{CZ}$ and single-qubit gates ($U$ rotations) only. In Qiskit, this is possible by passing the `basis_gates` argument (optionally including custom gates) to the [`transpile`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html) function.

However, in your case, first you have to define your $\sqrt{CZ}$ gate and then add to the Qiskit `StandardEquivalenceLibrary` the equivalence $CZ = \sqrt{CZ} \sqrt{CZ}$, since it is not included by default:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import CZGate
from qiskit.circuit.equivalence_library import SessionEquivalenceLibrary as sel

sqrt_cz = QuantumCircuit(2, name='$\sqrt{CZ}$')
sqrt_cz.append(CZGate().power(1/2), [0, 1])

cz = QuantumCircuit(2)
cz.append(sqrt_cz, [0, 1])
cz.append(sqrt_cz, [0, 1])
sel.add_equivalence(CZGate(), cz)
```

Finally, you should be able to transpile your original circuit and draw its decomposition:

```
from qiskit import transpile

tqc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['$\sqrt{CZ}$', 'u'])
tqc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it impossible to create a root iswap with only two root cz and single-qubit gates?

Comment: Yes, I think that is not possible. At least two $CZ$ or two $CX$ gates are needed.